# Quiet boot not working

Tags: boot, grub2, grub-efi

Following a blank installation of both Ubuntu 16.10 and 16.04 on my ASUS 1215N I'm experiencing problems with BIOS Quiet Boot functionality. Quiet Boot is a feature builtin in my laptop that prevents POST output to be displayed before bootstrap and thus shortening boot time a little bit.

After installing each operating systems (no dual boot, reverted to 16.04 due to this and other problems) this feature doesn't work anymore: on each reboot I get POST logs. This usually happens in particular conditions (like power outage) and makes me think that Ubuntu shutdown doesn't ends correctly.

I used to have Ubuntu 16.04 installed in dual boot with Windows 7 and Microsoft MBR on sector 0 (GRUB installed only on Ubuntu partition) and there was no problem.

Computer <s>is EFI</s> has old stile BIOS (not UEFI).

Tried to Google with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: EFI and UEFI are the same thing.

Comment: Do you have this line **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"** in your /etc/default/grub file? If your problem occurs after a power fail, you may only be seeing **fsck** checking the file structure on your disk. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema Yes, there is. As I said, this is related to Power-On Self Test, a BIOS thing, GRUB is untouched (and yes, I've double checked for that line). It used to occur only after a power fail (ie. dead battery), but now every time which makes me think the BIOS doesn't recognize the shutdown as "correct".

Comment: I need to be clear... is what you're seeing is the short BIOS POST messages, or fsck doing a file system check (because it sees a dirty file system), or do you see the entire boot process text (quite lengthy). Also, do you have the latest 902 BIOS installed? Check https://www.asus.com/support/Download/30/14/0/110/HrglRhH8D60Rmlv3/30/. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for helping me. What I see are BIOS POST messages. To be clear, first I get [this](http://i1156.photobucket.com/albums/p565/fiolkatopies1/01DSCF4501_zps09fa078d.jpg), followed by something like [this](http://i42.tinypic.com/54dhkk.jpg). Messages don't tell any specific error. Quiet boot is intended to suppress these messages, skipping directly to the GRUB (which, in my case, is quiet too). Usually boot is verbose after a power outage (like, checking everything is fine I guess) and this makes me think something in the BIOS is not set to tell the system was shut down correctly.

Comment: The two images you posted are almost the same, except the first one indicates that the BIOS hardware clock is not set correctly. The messages are totally BIOS generated, and happen long before GRUB gets involved. I would first try and set the BIOS hardware clock by entering the BIOS. If that doesn't fix the problem, then choose "reset BIOS to default". Let me know. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema Perhaps I haven't been crystal clear. Those images are examples. I do not get any error message. I just get the classic Asus Eee PC logo with the text "Press F2 to enter setup" and then the verbose POST log. Quiet boot should suppress this. No problem is detected. GRUB is still sleeping in the disk at that time, of course.

Comment: Oh, I thought the examples were current. Silly me. I'd still check that you have BIOS 902 as per my previous comment, and I'd still do a BIOS "reset to defaults". Let me know. Cheers, Al

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47191/discussion-between-samuele-pilleri-and-heynnema).